# ng-change breaking angular material dropdown with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$ngAnimateParentKey' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, ng-animate

I am adding angular material to my site. I am able to run the following without any issue:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Package</label>
    <md-select ng-model="vm.search.parameters.package">
        <md-option ng-repeat="package in vm.packages.list" value="{{package.id}}">
            {{package.name}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

But I need to trigger a function on change, so I need to add an `ng-change` like so:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Package</label>
    <md-select ng-model="vm.search.parameters.package" ng-change="vm.updatePhotographersList()">
        <md-option ng-repeat="package in vm.packages.list" value="{{package.id}}">
            {{package.name}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

It works the first time and even runs the function and returns the correct data, but it won't allow me to select from the dropdown again and the console shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$ngAnimateParentKey' of null
```

I have tried adding an ng-click to the the elements like so:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Package</label>
    <md-select ng-model="vm.search.parameters.package">
        <md-option ng-repeat="package in vm.packages.list" value="{{package.id}}" ng-click="vm.updatePhotographersList()">
            {{package.name}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

But these do not trigger at the correct time (seems like the function triggers before the `ng-model` updates). What is causing this error and what can I do to fix it?

Here are my dependencies:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't an issue with ng-animate at all. The problem was that my ui-router was triggering a reload. I'm still not sure why that was causing the problem, but here is the change that fixed it. I cahnged:

```
    $state.transitionTo($state.current.name, newStateParameters);
```

to:

```
    $state.transitionTo($state.current.name, newStateParameters, {notify: false});
```